# How to run java code from command line that has source code in 2 different packages?

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, command-prompt

So I want to run a class called WordFrequencyCounter which is nested in the folder: C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Computer Science\AI\Machine Learning\175\Assignment 2\src\ir\assignments\two\b

but when I go into that folder and run:

javac WordFrequencyCounter.java

it gives me an error because it says that it cannot find 
import ir.assignments.two.a.Frequency;
specifically it says package ir.assignments.two.a does not exist, but this file is located in:

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Computer Science\AI\Machine Learning\175\Assignment 2\src\ir\assignments\two\a

I also tried calling javac WordFrequencyCounter.java from within the folder: C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Computer Science\AI\Machine Learning\175\Assignment 2

but that does not work either. So what I want is to be able to compile and run WordFrequencyCounter and then feed it an input file that is located in 
C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Computer Science\AI\Machine Learning\175\Assignment 2 from the command line. I can do this from the IDE but can't get it to work through command line.

I think this is a classpath related problem but I couldn't find anything useful on this for my particular example, and nothing I tried worked.
[image]

Here's the main method for WordFrequencyCounter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);

    List<String> words = Utilities.tokenizeFile(file);

    List<Frequency> frequencies = computeWordFrequencies(words);
    Utilities.printFrequencies(frequencies);
}
```

Comment: Is WordFrequencyCounter in package ir.assignments.two.b ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to src folder and run

`javac -d . ir/assignments/2/b/MainClass.java`

and use `java ir.assignments.2.b.MainClass` to  run it.

Comment: Great the compilation worked. But I'm still stuck running code because I have an input file in the src's parent folder (Project folder). I added a picture of the file structure for clarification. Also, I was wondering how to do it by setting the CLASSPATH environment variable?

Comment: If it is a ClassPathResource run your code using java -cp ..;. ir.addignmanets.2.b.MainClass. This will add parent lib and current lib to jvm class path.

Comment: try  java -cp ..;. ir.addignmanets.2.b.MainClass ../inputfilename   This will pass the file path(relative path ) to java main